# unable to give id attribute to an element

Tags: d3.js, raphael

I am using d3 with raphael. my requirement is to create one x axis and than append to buttons on both the ends. but it is unable to give id to it.is there any way to give id or use elements. As i am naive i don't know much about it

```
    var raphael = new Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");
raphael.setStart();
d3_raphael = d3.raphael(raphael);


svg = d3_raphael.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width",svg_w)
.attr("height",svg_h);



    xAxis.scale(x)
svg.select("#x_axis")
    .call(xAxis);
d3_raphael.call(xAxis); 


svg.selectAll("#year_bar")
    .data([0])
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("id", "year_bar")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 4)
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr("height", 10);

   svg.selectAll(".year_button")
    .data([minYearFilter, maxYearFilter+1])
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "year_button")
    .attr("d", "M-7,4L-7,15L0,22L7,15L7,4L-7,4")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return i == 0 ? "min_year" : "max_year"; })
    .attr("selected", "false")
    .attr("y", 4);

        yearSetX(0, x(minYearFilter));      
    yearSetX(1, x(maxYearFilter+1));


   function yearSetX(i, x) {
if (i == 0) {
    barMinYearX = x;
debugger;
    var btn = d3_raphael.selectAll("#min_year");
} else {
    barMaxYearX = x;
    var btn = d3_raphael.select("#max_year");
}
//btn.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x + ",0)"; });
btn.attr("x",x);
btn.attr("y",0);
btn.attr("fill", "gray");
btn.attr("stroke","gray");

if ((barMinYearX != undefined) && (barMaxYearX != undefined)) {
    d3_raphael.select("#year_bar")
        .attr("x", barMinYearX+7)
        .attr("width", (barMaxYearX - barMinYearX - 13));
}
  }
```

Comment: If your comment is part of the question, edit the question and add the code to it.

Comment: @Mahm00d i have done as you told..

Comment: Where do you want an id adding? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Neil in my code i am creating a rectangle,year buttons to each one i need to give id to access it. as u see i am using these ids in yearSet function.

Comment: I think you will need to try and get this in to jsfiddle so that someone can help you.